# Rails 3 - Marking dependent items archived when parent is archived

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure the title really explains correctly what i'm trying to do so forgive me. I have a table called clients for an invoicing system i've built.  I also have tables called projects and invoices.

Here's an example (not the actual columns in the tables, just for an example) of my database structure.

```
Clients
    id
    name
    description
    archive

Projects
    id
    client_id
    name
    description
    archive

Projects
    id
    client_id
    project_id
    name
    description
    archive
```

I have created the ability to archive a given invoice, project, or client independently.  However, i wanted to see what the best way to do this would be if i wanted to have say the projects and invoices for a client to be automatically marked as archived when i archive the client.  My process would be this:

- Archiving a client would archive the client, all projects with that client id, and all invoices with that same client id.
- Archiving a project would archive the project and all invoices with that project id.
- Archiving an invoice just archives the invoice itself

NOTE: by "archived" i mean the archive bit gets flipped to 1 instead of 0 (not archived / active).

**By the way**, the way that you archive something is on the edit screen there is an "Archive?" checkbox that you would check off to archive the item.

I know that in my edit action in my controller i can just say something like `if archive == 1` then run additional sql update statements to update dependent items `else @object.save` to just save the data for the edited item.

## My question?

Is there a better way to do this? Is the way i mentioned generally the best practice? I am already using `:dependent => :destroy` elsewhere in the model to delete rows in associated tables when a "parent" item is deleted.  Is there something pre-built in to Rails that will allow me to mark things like i am trying to do through the relationships of the tables?

Thanks for any help with this!  Hope i explained the problem and question well enough, but let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be to create a `after_update` on the `Client` and `Project` model :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :archive_check

  private
  def archive_check
    projects.each{|p| p.archive = self.archive; p.save} if self.archive_changed?
  end
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :archive_check

  private
  def archive_check
    invoices.each{|i| i.archive = self.archive; i.save} if self.archive_changed?
  end
end
```

So when you save a client, the `archive_check` is triggered. And then if archived, it'll update all the related `projects`. Since you update the `projects`, the `archive_check` will also be triggered in the `Project` model for each invoice this time.

Comment: Awesome, that definitely gets me half way there!  I figured there was an easier/better way of doing it.  Now, what about if i mark a client or project as "not archived" (basically a reverse action).  I'm guessing i would put an else in the `archive_check` method?

Comment: Well actually, you want to test for an `archive` value change, and make sure it is passed on associated models? I'll edit the answer, easier way to do it than a `else`

Comment: I edited the answer. You can use `archive_changed?` to know when the value has actually changed. If so, we just copy this new value to the associated `projects`. Same thing each project and associated `invoices`

Comment: Hmm...so i changed the code to what you said and it still does update when i check archive, but it doesn't do anything when i uncheck it.  Well, i say it doesn't do anything.  If i try and "unarchive" a project, the project archive bit gets flipped but not the "child" invoices.  They still stay archived.  I looked in the server log and when unarchiving the select statement runs to find all the associated invoices but the update statement never runs after it.

Comment: I know why, it's fixed now. `p.archive = self.archive and p.save` was never executing `p.save` since we were evaluating the condition `p.archive = self.archive` which returns the value of `p.archive`, which is `false`.